# Using a VHD that includes snapshots in a new VM

Tags: hyper-v

We have what I hope is a recoverable problem. We had a drive crash and the export/backups of the VM & VHD it turns out were failing part way through (and of course no one was checking the logs). So no clean way to get that. What we lost was the Hyper-V program and any files it has for configuration.

This is on Windows 11 (latest version). It's all on the same computer, what we lost has a SSD on the computer. The drive that died was the C: drive so we lost all of the Hyper-V install, registry, AppData folder, etc.

What we still have are the VM & VHD files. The data. They are on the D: drive. And what we need is the virtual drive. If we get the VM back, that's nice. But I can create a new VM. I need that data on the VHD though.

The VM had 10 or so checkpoints so in Hyper-V the checkpoint tree was a descending series of nodes, each with one child. And that child had one child. And...

I created a new VM and pointed it to the VHDX file. No luck. On powering up it said it could not find a bootable media. Here's the files I have:

**VHD**

[image]

**VM**

[image]

**Snapshots**

[image]

Is there a way to recover this? I don't know Hyper-V well but I'm guessing the collection of VHD files does have the drive image. But telling Hyper-V to use all of it - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance that the data is wrecked now. The VHDX serves as the root of all the AVHDX files. If connecting to it and trying to boot from it modified even a single bit, then the entire child tree of AVHDXs is ruined. Third party data recovery tools exist, but it's impossible to say what your luck with them will be.

In the future, you should just try to reinstall Hyper-V and run a virtual machine import, pointing at the root folder of the VM. Import can figure out the snapshot status and automatically piece together the snapshot tree. Even though I'm skeptical that you'll be able to recover anything, you should at least try that with what you have now. It should be able to at least detect the VM. It will try to connect to whatever it determines is the active VM, which in turn will have a reference to the most recently active AVHDX. That will then follow its parent tree all the way back to the root VHDX. If you're lucky enough that the attach and boot attempt didn't modify anything, then it will all just work. You can then delete all the snapshots and Hyper-V will merge and flatten everything on its own.

If you want to try to rebuild the complete VHDX from the constituent VHDX and and AVHDX files, then you'll need to run each AVHDX through [Get-VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vhd?WT.mc_id=CDM-MVP-5002481). Each will have a **ParentPath** property:
[image: Get-VHD output with ParentPath selected]

Find the AVHDX that has no other AVHDX pointing to it as a parent. That will be the last in the chain. Work backward until you know the entire chain in reverse order. You can probably work by modified date, but the ParentPath is a more reliable indicator. Once you merge, you cannot go back, so get this right the first time. The merge command does not check if the disk file that you're working on has a child of its own. If it has a parent, it will merge it into that parent, effectively orphaning any children that it has. You can re-parent an orphaned VHDX with [Set-VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vhd?WT.mc_id=CDM-MVP-5002481), but it just amounts to extra busy work and you have to know who the new parent is or you'll have to go through your available disk files one at a time until you get it right.

Once you know the parental order, use [Merge-VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/merge-vhd?WT.mc_id=CDM-MVP-5002481), starting with the childless AVHDX.

```
Merge-VHD -Path childless.avhdx
```

[image: sample Merge-VHD]

If successful, this will automatically delete the merged child AVHDX. Move on to the next in your list.

In this case, I suspect that the final merge will fail, as the VHDX has probably been modified and its child no longer aligns. But, you won't know until you try.